# Merging tags [wifi] and [wlan]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Similar to [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2996/what-is-the-intended-difference-between-the-wifi-and-wireless-tags-should-t), I do not see a difference between [wlan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) and [wifi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi).
Especially [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2999/61486) answer says it all.

Comment: There is a difference being that wlan is commonly used to refer to the interface name, but whether a significant one..

Comment: @prusswan The fact that it might be taken to refer to the interface name (the tag has no description) is probably another good reason to get rid of it -- should we have tags like `wlp6so` or `em1` too?  `wifi` + `lan` should cover it...actually I notice `lan` only has one question, so a lot of those `wlan` ones probably do involve `wlan0`.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't that many [wlan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) questions. I think the best approach here is to manually retag them and let the system purge the tag.